# Rails MailChimp API Groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp

I'm using the mailchimp-api gem in a rails 4 project. I can successfully subscribe a users email to a list, but can't get users into the group I'm specifying.

In Mailchimp I setup a Group with the name "UserType" as a checkbox. It has two groups within "User" and "Tech".

[image]

Here is my subscribe code:

```
@mc.lists.subscribe(list_id, {'email' => email}, {'merge_vars' => { 'groupings' => [{'name' => 'UserType', 'groups' => ['User']}]}})
```

I'm not receiving any errors and the email is still successfully being inserted into the list. Any ideas on why the user isn't being inserted into the "User" group?

Answer (score 0):

Try add an array for each group into groupings.. In your case you should count 4 arrays....

See if my PHP code can help you:

```
'merge_vars' => array('fname' => $firstName, 'lname' => $lastName, 'groupings' => array(array('name'=> 'Test', 'groups' => array('Test1'))));
```